# mysql select last result in IN query

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am a beginner in mysql, I have two table. Log table contains (email,datetime,value) and another is tmp in which email exist.

I make query

```
select distinct email, datetime 
from Log 
where email in (select email from tmp) 
group by email;
```

in result of this is :

```
| email                      | datetime            |
+----------------------------+---------------------+
| aaa@gmail.com              | 2014-02-06 14:08:28 |
| bbb@gmail.com              | 2014-05-22 18:53:39 |
| cc@gmail.com               | 2014-05-22 18:51:19 |
+----------------------------+---------------------+
```

But the I need datetime should be latest, this query pick the first date (older). What should I change to get the latest date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due the fact you use a group by you can use an aggregation function  like max( ) if you want the more recent otherwise you can use min()

```
  select email, max(datetime )
  from Log 
  where email in (select email from tmp) 
  group by email;
```

and using group by you don't need distinct

Comment: @vegeta [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) ... that's how we roll here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select distinct email, datetime 
from Log 
where email in (select email from tmp) 
group by email
ORDER BY datetime desc
```

Comment: na , it gives me the false result

Comment: Sorry,Use asc instead desc...desc will return the result in descending order.

Comment: What is the `'..` trailing apostrophe and dots?

Answer (score 0):

you can use max:

```
select distinct email, max(datetime) 
from Log 
where email in (select email from tmp) 
group by email;
```